# Finding an expression in a file using Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a program for college in python3. The program takes in a user expression and file path then finds any line in the file that contains the expression. My problem at the minute is as follows.

I have a small dummy txt file im using to test it. The file contains:

```
Hello, My name is Evan
This is a text file
I am using it to help me code my program
I am coding my program in Python3
```

My main Python file is as follows:

```
# Necessary imports
import os

# Variables
userExpression = [] # Variable for user expression
userFile = [] # Variable for user file
fileLines = [] # Variable for lines of text in the users file
lineNum = 0 # Variable for keeping track of line numbers

userExpression = input("Please enter the expression you want to find: ") # Read in and store users expression
userFile = input("Enter the path of your file: ") # Read in and store file path of users file

myFile = open(userFile) # Opening user file

print("                                                          ") # Used to make output easier to read
print("HOORAY!! File found!")
print("File lines that include your expressions are found below: ")
print("                                                          ") # Used to make output easier to read

# Store each line of text into a list
for line in myFile:
    lineNum += 1
    if line.lower().find(userExpression) != -1:
        fileLines.append("Line " + str(lineNum) + ": " + line.rstrip('\n'))

# Print out file text stored in list
for element in fileLines:
    print(element)

myFile.close()
```

For one of my tests i inputted "am" as the expression i wanted to find. I got this as the output:

```
HOORAY!! File found!
File lines that include your expressions are found below:

Line 1: Hello, My name is Evan
Line 3: I am using it to help me code my program
Line 4: I am coding my program in Python3
```

The problem is that my program pulled out Line 1 because 'name' contains 'am'. Is there any way to fix it so that only lines 3 and 4 are outputted because they specifically contain 'am'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to detect " userExpression " (with spaces) so the program only gets "userExpression" by itself.

```
    #like this
    userExpression = " " + input("Please enter the expression you want to find: ") + " "
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and such a simple way to fix my problem! Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Modification goes as follows:
if pattern found in line and `whole_word` is set then explode line into words (with `split()`) and check if word is in it.
Display in grep format:

`file-name: line: line with pattern`

--

```py
whole_word = 1
(...)

for line in myFile:
    lineNum += 1
    if line.lower().find(userExpression) != -1:
        if whole_word:
            if userExpression in line.lower().split():
                print "%s: %d: %s" %(userFile, lineNum, line),
```

result:

```
>>> execfile("a1.py")
b: 3: I am using it to help me code my program
b: 4: I am coding my program in Python3
```

The whole change in diff:

```
--- a.py    2021-04-22 02:54:25.931342100 +0200
+++ a1.py   2021-04-22 02:57:10.620831400 +0200
@@ -7,6 +7,8 @@ userFile = [] # Variable for user file
 fileLines = [] # Variable for lines of text in the users file
 lineNum = 0 # Variable for keeping track of line numbers
 
+whole_word = 1
+
 userExpression = input("Please enter the expression you want to find: ") # Read in and store users expression
 userFile = input("Enter the path of your file: ") # Read in and store file path of users file
 
@@ -21,7 +23,9 @@ print("                                 
 for line in myFile:
     lineNum += 1
     if line.lower().find(userExpression) != -1:
-        fileLines.append("Line " + str(lineNum) + ": " + line.rstrip('\n'))
+        if whole_word:
+            if userExpression in line.lower().split():
+                print "%s: %d: %s" %(userFile, lineNum, line),
 
 # Print out file text stored in list
 for element in fileLines:
```